# Scraping json with a number of iterations for concatenating all dataframes

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

This is my lines for scraping json from url and concatenating dataframes with for loop iteration.

```
page = 1000
# this can be automated by soup (couldn't do this) or selenium (by clicking EXPORT button) but this should be more efficient...
df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(1, page+1):
    filteredurl = "https://api.XXXXXX.XXX/XXX" + str(i) + "XXX"
    JSONContent_i = requests.get(filteredurl).json()
    df = pd.concat([df, pd.json_normalize(JSONContent_i)])
```

The code exactly works but takes like forever. Is there anyway to do this more efficiently?

Comment: maybe first add responses to list and convert to DataFrame when you get all data.

Comment: maybe API has some restrictions and it doesn't allow to run so many requests in short time. OR maybe this server is slow and it can't send response faster.

Comment: @furas Thanks for the comment. Can you elaborate on that? What do you mean about the list here?

Comment: It works pretty fast in page = 100, but after 1,000, it is way slower. Thought there is a room to improve the iteration

Comment: normal `data = []` before `for`-loop, and `data.append( JSONContent_i )` in loop - and after loop use `pandas` only once to convert all to  `DataFrame`.

Comment: you could first check all urls without converting to pandas - to see if problem is slow connection or slow pandas. Maybe all problem is adding new data to longer, and longer `DataFrame`

Comment: try using `requests.Session()`